Colorless Rubik's cube with letters on every sticker
I am interested in a variant of the Rubik's cube puzzle in which the stickers have no color, but instead there are digits or letters written on every sticker so that in the original configuration, letters on every side have the same orientation. The cube is then scrambled, and one needs to reconstruct the original configuration based on the orientation of the symbols only. I assume that the orientations of the 6 faces are chosen in such a way that no 4 of them that form a loop have the same orientation (then the puzzle is certainly ill-defined).
To understand the problem better and to show how different group operations change the orientation of individual stickers, I want to make a visualization in Mathematica. I found very beautiful visualizations for the conventional Rubik's cube, for example this Wolfram Demonstrations Project by Roman E. Maeder:
https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/RubiksCube/
Can anyone suggest how I can modify its source code so that it displays symbols on every sticker and keeps track of their orientations as the group operations are applied?
Here is a simple sketch to illustrate what I am trying to get (the symbols don't need to be in alphabetical order, of course):

Has anyone encountered this kind of puzzle elsewhere?
